# What is primary difference between teams and communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, team-sites, communication-site

Both teams and communications sites have the owner, member, visitor group. The membership of this can be controlled by site owner.

Communications site doesn't have the O365 group/mailbox.

Is this the only major difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, major difference in terms of security between team site and communication site is that communication site security/permissions can be managed using SharePoint groups while security/permissions of team sites can be managed using both SharePoint groups and M365 groups.

There are few other differences between team sites and communication sites as mentioned here:

[image]

**Documentations**:

1. [Team Site vs. Communication Site: Which one should I choose?](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/community/team-site-or-communication-site?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [What is a SharePoint communication site?](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-sharepoint-topic-showcase-and-blank-communication-site-templates-94a33429-e580-45c3-a090-5512a8070732?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Communication Site vs Team Site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/communication-site-vs-team-site/m-p/84148?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Under team site - "All members are content authors" - does this mean the O365 group member, or SharePoint member group, or is this generic member in the sense logically any user ?

Comment: I'm not clear as to how the "Who creates content" is relevant. I mean is this a general recommendation or a hard rule?

Comment: It is not a hard rule. Any user who has member (edit) permission on the site (team/communication) via M365 group or SharePoint group will have access to edit pages and create content. If you want to prevent any user from editing the pages, remove them from members and add in visitors group.